# About null space (kernel of matrix)

Tags: vector-spaces

I follow the book  linear algebra byOtto Bretscher. It has a large number of exercise  problems but it has only  answers of odd numbered problems. I have tried some questions but have doubt that they are corrected or not??? And I not found any solution manual for it. So  in the end I posted these here in a image below. Please tell these answers are corrected or not. Also I know it is wrong to put questions in a image below, but I don't have any option ....
Sorry for this....[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that is simply impossible to read.  Why would you not have any option"?  That doesn't look hard to type.

Comment: I don't know how to type  it in mathematical form....

Comment: @user247327 pleass send me link where i learn to write mathematical expressions

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference mathjax reference

Comment: I had to rotate the image, and the handwriting is a little unclear, but I was able to read it. I don't find any problems with the logic. It looks good.

Comment: And FYI - A useful trick for figuring out how to do mathjax is when you see something somebody else posted that you would like to emulate, right-click on the expression and choose "Show Math As >> Tex Commands".